# why does it need cluster:monitor/main permission

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

ES 7.17 cloud is hosted in [https://xxx.elastic-cloud.com:9243]](https://xxx.elastic-cloud.com:9243%5D)

Using Java High Level REST client, I was able to connect to server using spring data ES 4.1.5(ES client 7.9.3). Now I update to spring data ES 4.4.1 (ES client 7.17.4). But it gives me permission issue.

```
"root_cause":[{"type":"security_exception","reason":"action [cluster:monitor/main] is unauthorized for user [xxxx] with roles
```

Why does it need this permission?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the client pings the cluster using the `/` endpoint and it's actually why the [`cluster:monitor/main` privilege](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/83179) is required.

I believe this was added after the 7.10.2 Opensearch fork.

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to have a link to this change?

Comment: I shared the link in my answer

Comment: Where can I find the reference for client to ping the cluster using the / endpoint? I guess  it doesn't do that in 7.9.

Comment: As I said, it must have been introduced after 7.10 to do a product check... i.e. they don't want an Elastic client pinging an Opensearch cluster and vice-versa, because they are two different products that diverged too much since the fork

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't really understand how ES cloud works. The ES cloud is actually on Azure. My admin doesn't want to grant this permission. So I need to show that ES client 7.17 sends out this ping request which requires this permission.

Comment: It was actually since 7.14. Here is a more complete explanation: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/1878#issuecomment-1016810630

Answer (score 0):

Val is right. / endpoint requests are being sent out.

I found out more details for my issue.

[HEAD / and GET / in spring data ES 4.4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73055858/head-and-get-in-spring-data-es-4-4-1)